# Parameter is Null always when passing from view to controller mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass page number value to controller so that with that page no value i can fetch the list, but the parameter is always null. 
Here is the code of

View Page

```
  @if (Model.First().page == 1)
            {


                <ul class="pagination disabled"><li class="disabled"><a href="#"> Previous </a></li></ul>
                <ul class="pagination" style="float:right;"><li>  <a href="/MovieGenre/Genre/@(Model.First().GenreID)?type=@(Model.First().GenreType)?PageNo=@(Model.First().page + 1)"> Next </a></li></ul>
            }
            else
            {

                <ul class="pagination"><li><a href="#"> Previous </a></li></ul>
                <ul class="pagination" style="float:right;"><li>  <a href="/MovieGenre/Genre/@(Model.First().GenreID)?type=@(Model.First().GenreType)?PageNo=@(Model.First().page + 1)"> Next </a></li></ul>
            }
```

Here is the Controller

```
public ActionResult Genre(int id, string type, int? PageNo)
        {
            if (PageNo == null)
            {
                PageNo = 1;
            }
            var client = new RestClient("https://api.APIProvide.com/3/genre/" + id + "/movies?page=" + PageNo + "&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&language=en-US&include_adult=true&sort_by=created_at.asc");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddParameter("undefined", "{}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            string Movies = response.Content;

            JavaScriptSerializer serialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            MovieByGenre_GetList_Class objMovieByGenre_GetList_Class = serialize.Deserialize<MovieByGenre_GetList_Class>(Movies);

            List<MovieByGenre_GetList_Class> lstMovieByGenre_GetList_Class = new List<MovieByGenre_GetList_Class>();
            lstMovieByGenre_GetList_Class.Add(objMovieByGenre_GetList_Class);

            List<GenreList_GetList> lstMovies_Genre_List = GetGenreList();
            if (lstMovies_Genre_List.Any())
            {
                objMovieByGenre_GetList_Class.GenreList = lstMovies_Genre_List;
                lstMovieByGenre_GetList_Class.Add(objMovieByGenre_GetList_Class);
            }

            objMovieByGenre_GetList_Class.GenreID = id;
            objMovieByGenre_GetList_Class.GenreType = type;
            return View(lstMovieByGenre_GetList_Class);
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check getters setters for model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the view, the link formed is to be changed.

```
<a href="/MovieGenre/Genre/@(Model.First().GenreID)?type=@(Model.First().GenreType)?PageNo=@(Model.First().page + 1)"> Next </a>
```

is to be changed to

```
<a href="/MovieGenre/Genre/@(Model.First().GenreID)?type=@(Model.First().GenreType)&PageNo=@(Model.First().page + 1)"> Next </a>
```

Tip: The valid query string has to start with "?" and the subsequent parameters need to be specified using "&".